# What is the correct way to construct this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, punctuation, grammaticality-in-context

What is the correct way to construct the following sentence from a grammatical and punctuation perspective?

> Example: Currently occupying the position of a server Moderator in the ''AVU'' group.

Should there be a comma after ''currently''? Are the prepositions ''of'' and ''in'' correct in this context? (It is from a resume.)

Comment: As a bullet point in a list (assuming the right context), there is nothing ungrammatical about it in the first place. However, I'd say that adding a comma *would* make it ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the context is a resume:

### Comma after currently?

Not necessary. Using one or not here doesn't do much to change the meaning, especially since we're not using a complete sentence.

### "Of" and "in" usage correct?

Yes. "In" is a correct preposition to denote inclusion in a group. "Of" is a correct preposition when naming a position. However, "Currently occupying the position of..." can be reworded to be more concise.

Given that the phrase is from a resume, some options:

- Currently a server Moderator in the "AVU" group
- Current position: server Moderator in the "AVU" group

Comment: I'd be stronger about the comma. It shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

*(I agree with Otomatonium's answer; just wanted to add some background information.)*

Strictly speaking, the "example" given is not a sentence (it has no subject). However, since the comments above indicate that the context is a resume, I'll answer on that basis.

- it is correct to omit the comma
- the prepositions are correct

It is normal in a resume to list a number of bullet points which would all form complete sentences when prefixed by a short phrase, including the subject and possibly a verb. This phrase is easily deduced from the context.

In your case, the omitted understood phrase might be "Boris is...". All the other bullet points listed with this one should form complete sentences if the same phrase were supplied before them.

This type of outline structure, where each point supplies part of a complete sentence (of which the other part is the same for all points), is certainly not the only valid way to write a resume. It is one effective mechanism for maintaining parallel form.